# jQuery - AJAX call returns count, IE8 will not get the value

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, firefox, internet-explorer-8

Using jQuery 1.9.1 & doing an AJAX call to a stored procedure that returns a count.  In the `success` part of the AJAX call, I do some processing with the data that is supposed to be returned.  It works in Firefox, but not in IE8.  I've confirmed the stored procedure is returning data each time (0 if nothing is counted, and a positive integer if something is counted).

```
success:  function (data) {
  NoteCount = $(data).find("NotesCounted").text();
  if (NoteCount > 0) {
      .... do some processing
      }
   }
```

In Firefox, this works & if there are X Notes counted, then the If statement is processed.  In IE8, the above code does not work - the if statement never fires & displays I've had in the code in IE8 never show the NoteCount > 0 (even when I have manipulated the test data to force it to be counted).

I am obviously doing something wrong with the above code, but do not know what.  Would appreciate anyone's assistance in getting this to work the same way in both Firefox and IE8.

Thanks!

-- EDIT --

The call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: myURL,
    dataType: "xml",
    success:  function(data) {
                 NoteCount = $(data).find("NotesCounted").text();
                 if (NoteCount > 0) {
                    .... processing ......
                    } // if NoteCount > 0
                 } // success
    });
```

There's code in the .... processing ...... section, but in IE8, it's never getting fired (in Firefox, it is).  This code needs to run in IE8 as well as in Firefox.

Comment: What does `data` look like? `find("NotesCounted")` could be a problem in IE8.

Comment: is your dataType set to xml?

Comment: You'll have to post more code, there's nothing really wrong with the above ?

Comment: Yes - I have:  `dataType: "xml",` as part of the AJAX call.

Comment: But is the text zero, and only zero, or is there whitespace. Is the returned markup/xml valid etc ?

Comment: @adeneo - If I put in a console.log statement, in IE8, it shows 0 even when I've manipulated the data to show > 0.  In firefox, doing the same thing, it returns > 0 when I do the same thing.  IE8 never returns > 0, so the if statement never fires.

Comment: @steve_o are you even getting to the if statement in IE8?

Comment: Did you try `cache : false` in your ajax call ?

Comment: @adeneo - yes, I do have `cache: false` in the call now, with no change in how it returns.  I can display what's returned by calling an XML2String function & the xml looks right.

Comment: Then you're not parsing it correctly, try using filter() if it's a root element you're looking for, try using first() or something similar to make sure you're only getting the text from the element you need, then try parseInt(NoteCount, 10) to make sure it's an integer etc.

Comment: The combination of your suggestions fixed my issue.  Thank you for your very helpful guidance!